# Guessing game, discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a discord bot guessing game (using python) but it keeps failing. I have looked at many similar posts and haven't found anything that helps.

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx):
  number = random.randint(1,100)
  await ctx.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, guess')
  for i in range(0,5):
    guess = await client.wait_for('message') **(see below the code)
        if guess.content == number:
          await ctx.send('You got it!')
        elif guess.content < number:
          await ctx.send('Higher!')
        elif guess.content > number:
          await ctx.send('Lower!')
      else:
        await ctx.send("You lost, type $play to play again.")
```

** normaly it would say: , check=check,
but that doesnt seem to work, it says, check not defined or something like that

the code seems to get stuck at either: `for i in range(0,5):`, or: `guess = await client.wait_for('message')`

could someone help?, or post a guessing game that works + explanation?

Comment: `check=check` assumes that you have defined `check` before. You can check if the message comes from the author for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to include your own `check`. **This looks like the following:**

```py
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
```

This ensures that only the message from the author of the command is recognized and accepted. We include this in the code.

Also, you can't use `</> number`, you will get the following error:

```py
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
```

To fix this, simply change `number` to a `str:`

```py
</> str(number)
```

**A possible code would be:**

```py
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel

    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    await ctx.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, guess')

    for i in range(0, 5):
        guess = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

        if guess.content == number:
            await ctx.send('You got it!')

        elif guess.content < str(number):
            await ctx.send('Higher!')

        elif guess.content > str(number):
            await ctx.send('Lower!')

        else:
            return # Or something else
        
    else:
        await ctx.send("You lost, type $play to play again.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Dominik, but i have tried several codes now, i even took out the 'for' part, but the code seems to get stuck at ,"guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check), it doesn't give an error it just doesnt do anything, when i go and do another command it does work. its rly weird,, like the bot doesnt stop waiting for the message

Comment: btw i tried ur code, nothing wrong with it but doesn't work, i get the 'error' wich is not an error, i talk about in the comment above

Comment: After 5 guesses the bot is not accepting an answer anymore, you defined that. I tested the code and it works fine for me. I had a typo, it is called `bot.wait_for`

Comment: thx ill try that now, you in each case helped to make me understand the check=check thing

Comment: you are a saint, it works, kinda janky got to fix some stuff but the bot is replying

Comment: The `else` message is not displayed after 5 attempts are over, I will add that in a moment.

Comment: it works perfectly now, i dont really know what you mean but i think i fixed the else message: (ill post the answer as an answer)

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. I made an edit to my answer. In order for *"You lost"* to be displayed, the actual `else` message must be relocated like in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you'd like to know, after two days (few hours a day) I got it to work (almost) flawlesly, sometimes it will give wrong hints but I can't fix that. Heres the code( I ended up using the @bot.event):

```
if msg.startswith('$play'):
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    await message.channel.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, you have 5 guesses, guess.')
    for guesses in range(0,5):
      guess = await bot.wait_for('message')
      print(number)
      if guess.content < str(number):
        if guesses == 4:
          await message.channel.send("Too many guesses, try again.")
          await message.channel.send("The number I was thinking of was " + str(number) + ".")
          break
        else:
          await message.channel.send("Higher!")
      elif guess.content > str(number):
        if guesses == 4:
          await message.channel.send("Too many guesses, try again.")
          await message.channel.send("The number I was thinking of was " + str(number) + ".")
          break
        else:
          await message.channel.send("Lower!")
      else:
        await message.channel.send("You got it! You guessed " + str(guesses+1) + " times.")
        break
```