# how to make a high low command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so im making a discord bot with discord.py, it is an economy bot. i want to add a highlow command, and cant figure out why my code isn't working. i have no errors, the only problem is it always outputs incorrect, even when its supposed to output as correct. here's my code. also db is done with repl.it

```
@bot.command(aliases=["hl", "starksgame"])
async def highlow(ctx):
    money = db[f"{ctx.author.id}"]
    hint = random.randint(1, 100)
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    money_to_add = random.randint(1, 500)
    tries = 1
    await ctx.send(f"your hint is {hint}")
    while True:
        guess_message = await bot.wait_for('message')
        if guess_message.author.id == ctx.author.id:
            if tries == 1:
                if guess_message == "high" and number > hint:
                    await ctx.send(f"correct, the number was {number}")
                    db[f"{ctx.author.id}"] = money + money_to_add
                    tries = 0
                elif guess_message == "low" and number < hint:
                    await ctx.send(f"correct, the number was {number}")
                    db[f"{ctx.author.id}"] = money + money_to_add
                    tries = 0
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f"incorrect, the number was {number}")
                    tries = 0
            else:
                return
```

Comment: The goal is to guess whether the hint number is larger or smaller than the target number?

Comment: the goal is to guess if the number is high or low compared to the hint number

Comment: Did you have your code print out the hint and number in order to debug it? As an aside, it might make more sense to swap the two cases: Have "low" mean "hint is lower than the number". I find that a bit more intuitive.

Comment: You may found your own solution but I also made an answer to that a while ago which includes all you are asking for. You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361326/guessing-game-discord-py-bot/67361474#67361474

Answer (score 1):

Hey there instead of doing `guess_message` you have to do `guess_message.content` or `guess_message.clean_content`

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, it needs to be guessed_message.content not guessed_message