# python: discord.py guessing game not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have imported all the necessary modules for the following;
When I Type `$game` on my Discord server the bot doesn't react.

```
async def game(self,ctx):
  number = random.randint(1,100)
  for i in range(0,5):
      await ctx.send("Guess")
      response = await self.bot.wait_for("message")
      guess = int(response.content)
      if guess > number:
          await ctx.send("The Number is greater")
      elif guess < number:
         await ctx.send("The number is smaller")
      else:
         await ctx.send("You guessed the number!!")
```

Comment: Have you decorated the function with `commands.command()`?

Comment: First off, refer to the above comment, second off, in `wait_for`, you're not checking if the user is the same one that ran the command and is in the same channel.

Comment: Is my answer to this question helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361326/guessing-game-discord-py-bot/67361474#67361474