# discord.py - Guessing game no response (updated)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The following code is supposed to run when I type `$play` on my discord server but nothing happens when I run it..

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.command(name="play")
async def play(ctx):
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel and m.content.isdigit()

  number = random.randint(1,100)
  await ctx.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, guess it')

  for i in range(0,5):
    guess = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    
    if int(guess.content) > number:
      await ctx.send("The number is greater")
    elif int(guess.content) < number:
      await ctx.send("The number is smaller")
    elif int(guess.content) == number:
      await ctx.send("You guessed the number!!.")
    else:
      return ("It has to be a positive integer between 1 to 100")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You lost, type $play to play again.")
```

Comment: Have you imported the following? `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: @Dominik I have; here is the [entirety of the code](https://replit.com/@fs0c13ty/Mr-Robot#main.py) ; the guessing game starts from line 45

Comment: Can you more deeply explain what is happening? when i copied your code it is working fine except it always tell that the number is greater even when I type 1000000

Comment: @loloToster Did you type ```$play``` to run the code? When I type ```$play``` on a channel of my Discord Server nothing happens.. No error either. I remember that it did end up running once when I was messing with the code and the same thing happened; it always showed greater.

Comment: It is showing greater because you have messed up `>` & `<` signs they should be inverted. And about not responding, can you put `print("test")` at the top of `play` command to check if it is even responding to `$play`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `on_message` event is blocking commands from working.

**Add the following to your `on_message` event:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  # Your next events

    await client.process_commands(message) # Process commands
```

- We added this because you have overwritten the normal `on_message` event.
- `process_commands` makes sure that `commands` are recognized.

*See the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) for more information.*

Comment: It finally worked! The other commands are still functional but for some reason when I try and run them it shows this on the console even though everything is still working just fine:`` ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found``` (when I use $hello)

Comment: The question is about why `commands` are not working, I gave an working answer to that. I would suggest you either open a new question for that or find solutions yourself. I made an answer to the exact same code a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361326/guessing-game-discord-py-bot/67361474#67361474