# Not sure how to continue this discord python code

Tags: python, discord.py

I have written a function named `guesstall` which is a number guessing game. I am trying to convert the code into a discord bot command. Discord users should be able to initiate the game by using `-guesstall`.

I am very new to Python, just started with discord.py today. Any help would be appreciated.

```
async def guesstall(message):
    n = int(random.randint(1, 50))

    gjett = 5

    while gjett > 0:
      await message.channel.send("Guess a number")
      t = message.content()
      time.sleep(1)
      if t == n:
       await message.channel.send("Your guess was correct")
       break

      elif t < n:
        await message.channel.send("The number is higher than your guess")
        gjett -= 1
        await message.channel.send("you have", str(gjett), "guesses left.")
        await message.channel.send("")

      elif t > n:
        await message.channel.send("The number is smaller than your number")
        gjett -= 1
        await message.channel.send("You have", str(gjett), "guesses left.")
        await message.channel.send("")

      if gjett == 0:
        await message.channel.send("You failed")
        await message.channel.send("The number was", str(n))

  if message.content.startswith("-guesstall"):
    await guesstall(message)
```

Comment: What's the issue? What are you trying to do that's not working? It's fine to be a beginner, but please explain to us what's going on. We can't guess.

Comment: I would suggest you watch some videos and read up some guides on how to create a basic discord bot. There is a specific way on indicating that the function is a command instead of checking if the messages starts with.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know you guys didnt know what I was trying to do. Basically, I am trying to make a guess number bot, what I am trying to do is that when I type -guesstall in discord, it asks me what number I want to type. If its right, I get correct, if its wrong, it tells me if the secret number is higher or lower than my guess

Comment: Is this helping for your "guessing" game? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361326/guessing-game-discord-py-bot/67361474#67361474

Comment: problem is your bot isn't waiting for a new input, it does check all the conditions, but when the user reenter a new answer, the attempts "gjett" resets to 5, so you basically end up playing a new game over and over again

Comment: why is that? Should I change the while loop into a for loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you defined the bot? Have you installed the required libraries? As everyone said, you should learn the basics of discord.py first!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the rewrite version of discord.py it will make it much easer